# Reuse custom authorizer for AWS ApiGW using CDK

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, lambda-authorizer

I would like to reuse a custom authorizer that was created using CDK in one repository for a new AWS ApiGW method that was created in another repo. Currently, there is no CDK built-in method for importing an existing authorizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to overcome the problem:

```
# Import rest api from the environment using ids
rest_api = RestApi.from_rest_api_attributes(self, "fromrestapiid",
                                                    rest_api_id=rest_api_id,
                                                    root_resource_id=resource_id)
# Retrieve or create an API method
method_resource = rest_api.root.resource_for_path(endpoint_path)

# Change the property of the resource using the existing authorizer id
method_resource = method.node.find_child('Resource')
method_resource.add_property_override('AuthorizationType', 'CUSTOM')
method_resource.add_property_override('AuthorizerId', authorizer_id)
```